# Showing all divs one by one

Tags: jquery

I ve many divs in asp page and I want to show them after the page load one by one using jquery.show() or jquery.fadein() I mean they will not be shown all together, they should be shown one by one.

```
<div class = "trip">Trip1</div>
<div class = "trip">Trip2</div>
<div class = "trip">Trip3</div>
<div class = "trip">Trip4</div>
```

Thanks for any response.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @j08691 +1500 to you sir

Comment: :) I'm sorry for that. I didnt try anything. I am kinda newbie in stackoverflow. I didnt think I should have said "thanks" I thank to the answers giving + vote. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @gdoron we all helped; so might be better not to accept an qanswer ;)

Comment: Is there a way to accept an answer, or just saying "thanks its working" is enough ? :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. He can just pick one, it doesn't matter which one if they are all good. What I usually do I picking the 1. Best answer. 2. The first to answer. but he should accept an answer like he wants.

Comment: @gdoron Sometimes I used to pick the answer of the slowest one or the one that has less points. ;) But sometimes SO needs a roulette, like here :D

Comment: OK, so I accepted the first one I tried and worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".trip").each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).delay(i*400).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k56n9/)

```
$(".trip").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 100).fadeIn();
});​
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.trip').each(function(index, element){
    $(this).delay(1000 * index).show(0);
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/RwMy7/11/)

Comment: +1 if you change it to `show(0)` and `hide(0)`. Right now it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".trip").each(function(i,o){
 $(o).delay(i*250).fadeIn();
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ibupud/2/edit